# Stop SKAction after a certain amount of time

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have a number of enemies that spawn at separate times in my game, and move using SKAction but at the end of each level I have a boss that spawns in. When the boss spawns I want the other enemies to stop spawning. I have a function for each enemy. I'm using the `withKey:` in  my `SKAction.sequence` for each enemy and then use the `removeAction(forKey: )` in the boss function to stop it but it doesn't work. Am I using this in a wrong way.

example of my code (only left in the SKAction code, removed all other code)

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
       //Spawn Enemy1
        run(SKAction.repeatForever(
          SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run() { [weak self] in
                              self?.addEnemy1()
                            },
                            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5.0)])))

}

func addEnemy1() {
        
        let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10)
        let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(y: -600, duration: 5.0)
        let actionRemove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        enemy1.run(SKAction.sequence([delay, actionMove, actionRemove]), withKey:"enemy1")
        
    }

func addBoss() {
        
        let move1 = SKAction.moveTo(y: size.height / 3.5, duration: 3)
        let move2 = SKAction.moveTo(x: size.width / 3, duration: 3)
        let move3 = SKAction.moveTo(x: 0 - boss.size.width, duration: 3)
        let move4 = SKAction.moveTo(x: 0, duration: 1.5)
        let move5 = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.2)
        let move6 = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.2)
        let move7 = SKAction.moveTo(y: 0 - boss.size.height * 3, duration: 3)
        let move8 = SKAction.moveTo(y: size.height / 3.5, duration: 3)

        let action = SKAction.repeat(SKAction.sequence([move5, move6]), count: 6)
        let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([move2, move3, move4, action, move7, move8]))
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move1, repeatForever])

        boss.run(sequence)
        
        enemy1.removeAction(forKey: "enemy1")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the wrong action. The action with key "enemy1" is:

```
SKAction.sequence([delay, actionMove, actionRemove])
```

which simply animates the enemy. Removing this only stops this sequence of actions temporarily. When `addEnemy1` is called again, the sequence of action is added again.

The action that spawns the enemy is the action that you run on `self` here:

```
    run(SKAction.repeatForever(
      SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run() { [weak self] in
                          self?.addEnemy1()
                        },
                        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5.0)])))
```

Yo should give a key to that action instead:

```
...
},
SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5.0)])), withKey: "spawnEnemy")
```

and then remove that from `self`:

```
removeAction(forKey: "spawnEnemy")
```

Comment: Sorry, stupid question but how do I remove from self or do i just do 'self.removeAction(forKey: "spawnEnemy")'. I now self is the object created. Sorry again still learning Swift. Thanks very much for your reply.

Comment: @user1857403 yes and that is the same as the last code snippet in my answer.